# When is it appropriate to write a "use" declaration versus writing the full namespace for a class?

Tags: php

Sometimes i write

`use Said\Class;`

at the top of my php file if i'm using the class as a parameter for the constructor or even if i'm instantiating.

But when is it more appropriate to just write the whole class name? Like:

`$service = new \Said\Class();` instead of declaring it?

I typically write it out if i'm using constants. But maybe you should always declare it at the top of the file. Not sure on efficiency or standards-wise.

Comment: Entirely a matter of taste, it certainly won't make any noticeable difference to performance

Answer (score 0):

Most namespaces are pretty long unlike your example, so using `use` greatly reduces line length on code which in turn makes it more readable.

Here is an example, which do you prefer?

```
<?php
namespace App\Exceptions;

class Handler extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler {
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException::class,
     ];
    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(\Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }
    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, \Exception $e)
    {
        if($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException)
        {
            abort(404);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Vs using use, which is much cleaner.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
     ];
    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }
    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
        {
            abort(404);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured as much. But just putting feelers out to see if there was some significance beyond brevity